# Possible to add "Template" selector to posts?

Tags: theme-development

I would like to apply layout templates to my posts, just like I can do with pages. For example, I have a template-wide.php that does not include sidebars and adds a special "wide" class to the content div.

At present, I can only use this template for pages. Is it possible to make it available to posts as well?

Comment: A more up to date overview can be found here: [Can I assign a template to a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23674/can-i-assign-a-template-to-a-custom-post-type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Custom Post Template Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/).

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Thanks! Hate to have to resort to a plugin but I'll probably just bake the bits into functions.php. What with WP 3+ taking on more of a cms personality, why continue to limit template selectors to page post types in core?

Comment: 4.7 has it in core ...

Answer (score 2):

WordPress 3.1 includes a new feature called Post Formats. It's a little like how Tumblr lets you have different formats for different kinds of content, and I think it could be adapted to what you are trying to do. I haven't actually used it yet, but [here's an introduction](http://lisasabin-wilson.com/wordpress-3-1-post-formats-reference) I found that might be helpful.