# Adding a meta box to determine the sidebar

Tags: posts, metabox, post-meta, sidebar

I was trying to customize my WordPress, and I have added some custom meta boxes (it adds custom field) to add values in it, but I don't know how to do this one...

I want to a Meta Box, which will be a drop down menu. The value of this metabox will determine which sidebar to use in the post. Here's the picture:

[image]

Comment: There are some solutions available to add a template selector to posts and custom post types. For example the one mentioned in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11194/22534) or [this one](https://github.com/wordpressplugineer/custom-post-type-template-selector). Surely there are more, but those you have to research yourself. If you want some more and concrete help here, you should improve your question, best with some code - see [ask] for some help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [metabox plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) and active:

```
/**** Add this code in your function.php ****/

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'post_sidebar',         
    'title' => 'post Sidebar',      
    'pages' => array('post'),       
    'priority' => 'low',            
    'fields' => array(          
            array(
                'name' => 'Post Sidebar',               
                 'id' => 'post_sidebar',        
                 'type' => 'select',                            
                 "options" => array( "0" => "OFF", "1" => "Left side", "2" => "Right Side"),
            ),
        )
);
if ( class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) )
{
    foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box )
    {
        new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
    }
}

/**** after single.php on get value using this one option ****/  

$sidebar_value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'post_sidebar',true);

if($sidebar_value == 1 && $sidebar_value!=0){
    // Add sidebar code for left side
}

if($sidebar_value=='2' && $sidebar_value!=0){
    // Add sidebar code for right side
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to add meta boxes, so I changed the function into native metaboxes... Nice idea to use it... ;)